# MATLAB table of TeX characters?

Tags: matlab, tex

In the online documentation on mathworks.com, where is the table of the subset of TeX characters that MATLAB supports?

I'm used to finding it easily and I can't: on this page http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f0-4741.html#f0-28104 they have a note saying:

> For a list of symbols and the character sequences used to define them, see the [table of available TeX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text_props.html#String) characters in the Text Properties reference page.

but the hyperlink seems messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never mind, found it; it's there where the hyperlink was, but you have to look at the TeX Character Sequence Table and click on the little unobvious down-arrow to get the table to display.